# How to do generate some scenarios using a predicted cdf in Matlab or Python?

Tags: python, matlab, probability, sample, cdf

I have used Matlab but I also welcome python for the solution.

I have a predicted CDF (i.e., CDF^) of a random variable `Var` and would like to generate N scenarios using this predicted CDF (CDF^). Here is what I have done. I would like to know if this method makes sense and also how can I automatically generate N scenarios in step 3.

1) I fit an assumed cumulative distribution function(let's say Weibull) using the MLE on CDF^ and obtained the corresponding parameters of the fitted function.

2) Using these parameters, I have plotted the pdf of the assumed distribution.

3) In this step, I am not sure what to do and how! Basically I guess, I should discretize `var` and find the corresponding probability of each segment by calculating the area of each rectangle.

4) How can I plot my original data (var) in PMF form since it is already in CDF form?!

```
var= [ 0.001    0.01    97  145 150 189 202 183 248 305 492 607 1013];
cdf_prob = [0.01, 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 0.35, 0.45, 0.50, 0.55, 0.65, 0.75, 0.85, 0.95, 0.99];
                             % cumulative prob.
a= mle(var, 'distribution', 'wbl');              
plot(var, cdf_prob, 'o-')                         % my data
hold on
xgrid = linspace (0, 1.1*max(var));
plot (xgrid, wblcdf(xgrid,a(1),a(2)));            % fitted cdf

figure(2)                                         % fitted PDF
pd= makedist('wbl', 'a', a(1),'b', a(2));
y=pdf(pd, xgrid);
plot(xgrid,y)
```

Step 3:
[image: Step 3]

Comment: Have you looked at [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html)? I think there are numerous related posts that do this ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52902148/8239061), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52917347/8239061), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58580684/8239061)).

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled. Are you trying to generate *N* samples from a defined distribution?  We can do that.  Also, why both the python and matlab tag?

Comment: I couldn't find the answer to my question in those posts directly. But yes, I have a predicted CDF that we know it should be in Weibull shape. I have obtained the parameters of it using MLE. Now I want to generate N samples from the obtained Weibull distribution. Moreover, How can I plot my data (var) in a PMF format since it is in a CDF shape. @SecretAgentMan

Comment: A solution in Python would also meet my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Generating Samples:**
You can generate samples from a distribution many, many ways.  If you already know you are going to use a specific distribution, like the [Weibull distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weibull_distribution), then two easy options are:

1. Use [`makedist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/makedist.html) and [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html),<sup>[1]</sup> or
2. Use [`wblrnd()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/wblrnd.html).

Both require use of the Statistics toolbox. Toolbox-free approaches are also possible. 
Recommend avoiding naming a variable `var` as it masks the [`var()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/var.html) function.

```
% MATLAB R2019a
a = [209.2863 0.5054];        % a = mle(var, 'distribution', 'wbl');  % from OP code
NumSamples = 500;
pd = makedist('Weibull',a(1),a(2))    

% Method 1
X = random(pd,NumSamples,1);

% Method 2
X2 = wblrnd(a(1),a(2),NumSamples,1);
```

**Plotting the original data:**
If the data is assumed from a continuous distribution, such as the Weibull distribution, then one should use a [probability density function (PDF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) to visually show relative chance rather than a discrete [probability mass function (PMF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_mass_function). PMFs only apply to discrete variables.  Note that [cumulative distribution functions (CDFs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function) apply for both continuous and discrete random variables.

This can be done with the `'Normalization','pdf'` name-value pair in the [`histogram()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/matlab.graphics.chart.primitive.histogram.html) properties. To achieve better results, it is often advisable to adjust the number of histogram bins (in the properties), but with only 13 data points, this is of limited value.

```
h = histogram(var,'Normalization','pdf')
h.NumBins = 13;
```

You can also overlay the fitted distribution against the empirical data.

```
figure, hold on
h = histogram(var,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','Data');
xLimits = xlim;
Xrng = 0:.01:xLimits(2);
plot(Xrng,pdf(pd,Xrng),'r--','DisplayName','Fit')
xlabel('Var')
ylabel('Probability Density Function (PDF)')
legend('show')

% Adjust these manually
ylim([0 0.02])
h.NumBins = 13;
```

**Alternatives:**<sup>[2]</sup>

You can use [`fitdist()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/fitdist.html) which can fit a [kernel density](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.kerneldistribution.html) and still permits using all the functions for [Probability distribution objects](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/working-with-probability-distributions.html), including [`random()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.random.html) and [`pdf()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/prob.normaldistribution.pdf.html).

Notice I've [truncated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_distribution) the distribution since the Weibull has a support on `[0, inf]`.

```
pd2 = fitdist(X,'Kernel')
pd2t = truncate(pd2,0,inf)
```

Then plotting is still relatively easy and similar to the previous example.

```
figure, hold on
h = histogram(var,'Normalization','pdf','DisplayName','Data');
xLimits = xlim;
Xrng = 0:.01:xLimits(2);
plot(Xrng,pdf(pd2t,Xrng),'r--','DisplayName','Fit')
xlabel('Var')
ylabel('Probability Density Function (PDF)')
legend('show')
h.NumBins = 13;
```

A remaining alternative is to exploit the [`ksdensity()`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/ksdensity.html) to get the plot.

---

<sub>[1] [Generating samples from Weibull distribution in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53288005/8239061)

[2] Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56759220/8239061</sub>